# How can I remotely delete sensitive data and log out from a stolen Mac?

Tags: security, remote-control

Is there any *software* or a *procedure* that would allow me to

- log out of all services (gmail, dropbox etc.)
- and/or delete any sensitive data remotely

...from a machine that has been stolen?

Comment: iCloud's Find my Mac service allows for remote wipes, securely removing everything on the lost or stolen device.

Comment: [Related topic on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/355624/how-to-find-my-stolen-macbook).

Answer (score 2):

## [Find my Mac](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/find-my.html)

Find my Mac is free and part of iCloud. Included features are:

- localize your Mac (internet connection required, Email notification)
- remotely lock your Mac to protect privacy
- remotely wipe your hard drive
- play a loud sound
- display personal messages on the Mac

[image] [image]

You need a Mac computer with Lion to use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the password will log all devices out and force them to prompt for a new password. For things like web-based gmail, this stops them accessing your email.

Unfortunately, for things like Dropbox where the data is already on your computer it won't delete it - although you could use find my mac just to wipe the entire computer (provided it has an internet connection) and start again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Undercover by Orbicule](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/index.html)

[image]

> Undercover is the premier theft-recovery software for the Mac, iPhone or iPad. This revolutionary program helps you **locate and recover your stolen devices**. Thanks to the new UndercoverCenter web app, users can **follow** their **stolen devices in real-time**.
>
> available for both OSX and iOS

- recover a stolen mac
- get the location
- get photos of the thief
- get screenshots of your OS

You can take a look at their [recover stories](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/mac/recovery.html).

A detailed description of [how it works](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/mac/works.html) can be found on their website.

**Money-back guarantee**

> If we can not recover your stolen Mac, we will fully refund Undercover. Of course we still offer our traditional money-back guarantee: if
> you are not satisfied with Undercover, you will get a full refund
> within 30 days of purchase. No questions asked.

**NOTE:**

You may note that this software will not immediately wipe your hard drive. This is very important, because **your computer needs to be online for localization**. This software acts in the background making a potential thief feel safe in using your computer. You can still see what a thief is doing by watching transmitted screenshots.

Comment: Undercover can also simulate a hardware failure making the computer unusable within 30 minutes, even when the Mac is not online.